# How to divide $10100 \div 2$ with long division?

Tags: education

How to divide $10100 \div 2$? I'm trying to divide 10100 by 2 with pen & paper and getting **550** as answer which is incorrect **(**Right answer is 5050)**. Literally, I think I have forgot primary level math. Could you guys help me to solve this problem with proper step by step guideline? Thanks in advance!

Here I got a long division solution but not clear to me: [Long Division Solution](https://www.symbolab.com/solver/step-by-step/%5Cfrac%7B10100%7D%7B2%7D)

Comment: $$\dfrac{10100}{2} = \dfrac{10000 + 100}2 = \dfrac{10000}2 + \dfrac{100}2 = 5000 + 50 = 5050$$

Comment: @an4s Thanks for reply. But Could you please solve this with long division?

Comment: What's not clear about the linked solution you posted?

Comment: @runway44 Actually I have forgot that method of long division. That's why linked solution is confusing to me.

Comment: $2$ goes into $1$ a total of $0$ times.  Thus, $0$ becomes the hundreds digit of the quotient.

Answer (score 1):

The long division algorithm starts at the most significant digit of the dividend and works its way down. In this case since $1<2$ we start with $10$, divide by $2$ to get $5$ as the leading digit, then subtract $2\times 5$ from $10$ to get $0$, so the next digit is $0$, then $1<2$ again and repeat to get $5050$ in the end.

See [here](https://www.mathsisfun.com/long_division.html) for an illustrated example.

Answer (score 1):

Because writing this in comments results in loss of formatting:

```
   5050 <-- quotient
  -----
2)10100
  10
  --
    10
    10
    --
        <-- remainder
```